# Scraping a web page

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the following web page: http://www.qedu.org.br/escola/112633-militar-de-salvador/enem?edition=2009. Searching the internet, I found the following script:

```
fetch_attendance <- function (year) {
url <- paste0 ("http://www.qedu.org.br/escola/112633-colegio-militar-de-   salvador/enem?edition=", year)
date <- url%>%
httr :: GET ()%>%
httr :: content ('text', encoding = 'utf-8')%>%
xml2 :: read_html ()%>%
rvest :: html_nodes (xpath = '// div [@ class = "span4 score-ct"] / p [1]')%>%
html_text ()%>%
gsub ("^ \\ s + | \\ s + $ | score", "",.)
date
}

library (plyr)

res <- ldply (2009: 2016, fetch_attendance, .progress = "text")
```

However, the result is as follows:

```
> res <- ldply (2009: 2016, fetch_attendance, .progress = "text")
=========================================== ===================== | 100%
> res
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1 97% 635pts 605pts 595pts 659pts 735pts
2 97% 635pts 605pts 595pts 659pts 735pts
3 97% 635pts 605pts 595pts 659pts 735pts
4 97% 635pts 605pts 595pts 659pts 735pts
5 97% 635pts 605pts 595pts 659pts 735pts
6 97% 635pts 605pts 595pts 659pts 735pts
7 97% 635pts 605pts 595pts 659pts 735pts
8 97% 635pts 605pts 595pts 659pts 735pts
```

That is, it only returns the results of the year 2009. Could anyone help me?
I would also like to get the values ​​for the years 2010 to 2016.

Comment: I think you can't as the website requires authentification to access other pages (probably to avoid web scraping which is btw most of the time illegal). FYI, I think the output you get is for 2016 (the default page) not 2009.